# Can I tailor a maven build based on platform?

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

Specifically, I run the `launch4j-maven-plugin` plugin to generate me an `.exe` file. This only works on Windows, so I was wondering if I could 'opt-out' of this step on other platforms?

The plugin is tied to the execution phase like this

```xml
<plugin>
...
<execution>
     <id>l4j-clui</id>
     <phase>package</phase>
     <goals>
          <goal>launch4j</goal>
     </goals>
</execution>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap that plugin under separate [build profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and just enable that profile on the build that you want

**For example:**

```xml
<project>
  ...
<profile>
<id>generate-exe</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!_- your plugin configuration -->
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
  ...
</project>
```

Now pass parameter while launching maven to specify profile

**For example:**

```sh
mvn clean install -Pgenerate-exe
```