# Can a pom.xml file have multiple build tags?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Can a pom.xml file have multiple build tags? Or is only one build tag allowable throughout the file?

Comment: Could you please explain what "build tag" means here?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with multiple build tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple [build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in a single `pom.xml`, each with different `<build>`
 configuration and you can choose which profile to build with

---

**Related**

- [Can I tailor a maven build based on platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978975/can-i-tailor-a-maven-build-based-on-platform)