# Always clean certain module in maven build

Tags: maven, module, multi-module

How can I figure out which modules will be built in a multi-module maven project before actually building them. Why:

- Need to always clean certain modules (note: Not all modules)

**Example**

---

Say I have four modules:

- Module A
- Module B
- Module C (dependent on module A)  (Always clean this before building)
- Module D (dependent on module C)

**Execution cases**:

- Case 1: `mvn install`  will build all four modules A,B,C,D
- Case 2: `mvn install -pl A` will build module A
- Case 3: `mvn install -amd -pl A` will build module A,C,D
- Case 4: `mvn install -am -pl D` will build module A,C,D

In case 1, 3, 4: Clean C before building.

In case 2: Skip cleaning C

**Alternates**

---

- Modify my build script to first figure out if C will be build, and run `mvn clean -pl C` beforehand
- Add some plugin to module which always cleans this particular module, if one exists?

---

*For the curious folks, why I need this is at all is because my module C has some plugins which do not always work without doing a maven clean on the module*

Comment: Which plugins do not work without a clean? Sounds strange.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I am sending a command-line option to the maven build, which affects a certain module.  In order for the build to work, that module needs a clean build every time.  The first answer below solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

From this link https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html

The following XML will force clean on an project.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>auto-clean</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Maven XML succinct as ever :)

Answer (score -1):

[Create a build profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978975/can-i-tailor-a-maven-build-based-on-platform) and mark clean plugin's execution to `<skip>true</skip>` for the module you don't want to clean in this build profile

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
           <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Jigar. Even if I think I need the opposite, but I think I got the direction. Let me try invoking maven-clean-plugin from maven-install-plugin.

Comment: you can't do that AFAIK, you can tie clean's execution from `install` phase