# Maven plugin execution at begining of dependency chain

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml, multi-module

I have three maven projects: A -> B -> C. To better explain situation I show pseudo pom.xml's:

A pom.xml

```
<groupId>X</groupId>
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
```

B pom.xml

```
<groupId>X</groupId>
<artifactId>B</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>X</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

C pom.xml

```
<groupId>X</groupId>
<artifactId>C</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>X</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I would like to execute maven plugin just in A project and then automatic in other ( B and C) like a chain, when I execute in B then also just in C would be automatic too. The problem is that in A project there is no information about B (I think). Changing pom's structure is extremity.

Do you have some idea how do it? I will be grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

maven's plugin's execution is tied to particular phase of maven's build lifecycle, for example surefire plugin by default ties to `test` phase

now consider you have a plugin that you want to execute in all project as a chain, you would have to [create a separate build profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978975/can-i-tailor-a-maven-build-based-on-platform) and tie your plugins execution after validate phase

and invoke `mvn validate` so it life cycle will go to just one phase (i.e. validate) and it will invoke your plugin like a chain

Comment: I am little confused. I have to add additional information to my user maven settings.xml (I think), but I don't see how to link to my projects (A, B, C) and my plugin to execute. Cen you explain me a little closer?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can approach this is (if you haven't tried it yet) is: Keep a root pom.xml with the following:
    ...
    ...

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
   <modules>
     <module>A</module>
     <module>B</module>
     <module>C</module>
   </modules>
 ....
 ...
```

This will "act" like a chain.