# Multiple wsdl2java goals in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I need two wsdl2java goals in my pom.xml, and I want the java files to be written to two different folders. Can someone please tell me how do I do it? I have the below content in my pom.xml currently, and I see its only working for the first wsdl2java goal, but not the second one.

```
   <build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>generate-sources</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <configuration>
                 <sourceRoot>target/generated-sources/test/java</sourceRoot>
                 <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                       <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/test/GetInfo.wsdl</wsdl>
                       <extraargs>
                          <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                          <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                          <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                          <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                       </extraargs>
                       <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
                       <faultSerialVersionUID>1</faultSerialVersionUID>
                    </wsdlOption>
                 </wsdlOptions>
              </configuration>
              <goals>
                 <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>generate-sources</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <configuration>
                 <sourceRoot>target/generated-sources/testOne/java</sourceRoot>
                 <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                       <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/testOne/CustomerDetails.wsdl</wsdl>
                       <extraargs>
                          <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                          <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                          <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                          <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                       </extraargs>
                       <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
                       <faultSerialVersionUID>1</faultSerialVersionUID>
                    </wsdlOption>
                 </wsdlOptions>
              </configuration>
              <goals>
                 <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create two [different build profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978975/can-i-tailor-a-maven-build-based-on-platform) and invoke `mvn` twice, once for both profile, or try multiple execution with different configuration [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239786/how-to-invoke-the-same-maven-build-twice-in-one-call)

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do it?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978975/can-i-tailor-a-maven-build-based-on-platform it has an example of build profile, so create such two build profile and then invoke them one by one

Comment: or try with a system property and do it twice with different value

Comment: How do I invoke both the goals simultaneously?

Comment: oh may be even simpler do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239786/how-to-invoke-the-same-maven-build-twice-in-one-call